# Installing the Eclipse OpenCL plugin without Internet access

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, opencl, eclipse-cdt

I: ...

- have some (relatively recent) version of Eclipse
- Want to install the [OpenCL development tool plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/opencl-development-tool)
- have the Update site URL: http://p2.ngms.hu/releases/luna
- don't have an Internet connection on the target machine
- can copy files to the target machine
- have another machine, connected to the Internet through a proxy, to work on (but it may not be the same OS distribution, same hardware etc. as the target machine.)

and I'm failing to manage to install the plugin.

I've tried [this guide](https://mcuoneclipse.com/2014/07/03/replicating-an-eclipse-update-site-for-offline-usage/) on replicating an update site for offline usage, but - the replication command did not work for me, on a Linux system:

```
/opt/eclipse/eclipse -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository.mirrorApplication -source  http://replicate.me.com/path -destination /path/to/local-mirror
```

this just started Eclipse.

If I try to visit the update site URL, I get a "connection reset" message (although, to be honest - I'm behind a proxy, so maybe that's the reason for that.)

So, how can I download (and install) this plugin?

Comment: I guess the easiest way is to install it from an existing installation (in which you installed the plugin and then copied to the target computer) via _File > Import...: Install > From Exisiting Installation_. For headless applications like the p2 mirror application use `eclipsec` instead of `eclipse`.

Comment: @howlger: 1. `eclipsec` is not part of the Eclipse (CDT) distribution. Where do I get it from? 2. I don't have an existing installation...

Comment: 1. `eclipsec` is part of the Eclipse IDE packages. Please link to the download of the _"Eclipse (CDT) distribution"_ you have; _"relatively recent version"_ is not a reliable version number and please be also more specific about the OS. 2. `/opt/eclipse/` is your existing installation on the machine that has internet access and which can be copied to the target machine without internet access, right?

Comment: 1. I don't have the download link, but it's Eclipse CDT "version 2018-09 (4.9.0) build 20180917-1800". 2. Yes, I guess I can go that route.

Comment: Hmmm. it looks like that server is dead. Is someone else able to access it? http://p2.ngms.hu/

Comment: I wouldn't call a release that is 7 releases behind a _relatively recent_. Independent of this, the update site seems to be permanently gone, as you have already noticed yourself. But there are still the [sources](https://bitbucket.org/ngmsopencl/workspace/projects/PROJ), so you can easily create an update site by yourself. Do you need help with that?

Comment: @howlger: Actually, yes; if you can link to somewhere relevant, that would be nice. Then I'll be able to close this question. Also - "relatively recent" is, well, a relative term. I have to work with a lot of software from 5 and 10 years ago.

Comment: I have [here an Eclipse plugin project on GitHub where automatically an update site is generated](https://github.com/howlger/Eclipse-Help-Modernized). You could use this as a template with minor modifications. However, this would require some basic experience with Eclipse plugin development.

Comment: @howlger: I've asked [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62679101/1593077) about this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, apparently the update site is dead, so the plugin can't be installed in the usual ways, anyway. It seems the plugin sources still exist in [some form](https://bitbucket.org/ngmsopencl/workspace/projects/PROJ), but using them is a [different question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62679101/1593077).

Thanks to @howlger.