# How do I produce an installable form of an Eclipse plugin from "sources"?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt, update-site

An update site for a plugin I want to use, [OpenCL development tool](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/opencl-development-tool), is dead. However, it seems some form of the sources is [available](https://bitbucket.org/ngmsopencl/workspace/projects/PROJ):

```
hu.ngms.opencl.aggregator      19.4 kB  2015-04-08      
hu.ngms.opencl.common         131.4 kB  2015-04-08      
hu.ngms.opencl.editor         829.4 kB  2015-04-08      
hu.ngms.opencl.feature        148.6 kB  2015-04-08      
hu.ngms.opencl.product        188.6 kB  2015-04-08      
hu.ngms.opencl.projectwizard  741.7 kB  2015-04-08
```

I'm not an Eclipse developer, but I was hoping I could recreate the plugin in some form I could use to install it in my installation of Eclipse (which may be Eclipse CDT 18.09 and may be later than that; if the Eclipse version is an issue, I'd like to know that too.) Specifically, a zipped update site with [this installation procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16074606/1593077) would be nice.

How can I do this?

Comment: Here we go: [GitHub project](https://github.com/howlger/hu.ngms.opencl), [update site](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/howlger/hu.ngms.opencl/update-site/staging) ([update site download](https://github.com/howlger/hu.ngms.opencl/archive/update-site.zip)), but not yet tested. Worth a bounty?

Comment: @howlger: Please make that an answer, so I can accept it. But please also explain what exactly you did to generate update-site contents from these files. One last thing: In the zip file, everything is under a folder named `staging/`; that confuses Eclipse, so I had to unzip and point it to within that directory. Then it worked :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having the sources, you can create an update site using the Maven plug-in Eclipse Tycho, which I have done for you [here](https://github.com/howlger/hu.ngms.opencl):

1. **Fork** the [original Git repositories](https://bitbucket.org/ngmsopencl/workspace/projects/PROJ) (or to be more precise and because the sources were split across multiple repositories, I only forked `hu.ngms.opencl.product`, moved everything into a subfolder and just copied the content of the non-empty repostiories into my repository; for simplicity's sake, but with losing the history of the other repositories)
2. In the root directory add a parent [**`pom.xml`**](https://github.com/howlger/hu.ngms.opencl/blob/master/pom.xml) file and [enable Tycho](https://github.com/howlger/hu.ngms.opencl/blob/master/pom.xml#L22-L39)
3. Add [.mvn/extensions.xml](https://github.com/howlger/hu.ngms.opencl/blob/master/.mvn/extensions.xml) to enable **POM-less** Tycho and delete the no longer required `pom.xml` files in the subfolders
4. In the `pom.xml` file, add the [**target platform as p2 repository**](https://github.com/howlger/hu.ngms.opencl/blob/master/pom.xml#L9-L15) (this is sufficient, but a separate target definition file would be better here since it would allow a more specific definition of the target platform)
5. For the **update site**, add a [`category.xml`](https://github.com/howlger/hu.ngms.opencl/blob/master/update-site/category.xml) file into a subfolder
6. In the `pom.xml` file, add the subfolders as [modules](https://github.com/howlger/hu.ngms.opencl/blob/master/pom.xml#L17-L20):

   - Both plug-ins, `hu.ngms.opencl.editor` and `hu.ngms.opencl.projectwizard`
   - Feature: `hu.ngms.opencl.feature`
   - Update site (`update-site`)
7. Run Maven `clean verify`

   - At the first attempt everything except the update site was successfully built. The removal of the unnecessary (since everything here is platform independent) [listing of all supported platforms](https://bitbucket.org/ngmsopencl/hu.ngms.opencl.feature/src/2e61ed4984d4c8e5a840e31e14b4a0c3611bc696/feature.xml#lines-7:10) solved the problem. Alternatively, an older Eclipse target platform with 32 bit support could have been used instead.
8. Add [my generic GitHub action](https://github.com/howlger/hu.ngms.opencl/blob/master/.github/workflows/continuously.yml) which is triggered on push to automatically **run Maven and publish the update site** as a Git branch (without history to prevent the Git repository from growing).

For more details see [*Eclipse Tycho for building plug-ins, OSGi bundles and Eclipse applications - Tutorial*](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html).